# iReport 5.1.0 image results in a display error

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have this sample report designed in iReport 5.1.0 and inserted just an image and trying to preview, system throws "Error Displaying Report Page. See the console for details". However there are no errors in console. There are no issues with 4.0.2. What am I missing here?

The template for 4.0.2 version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test-402" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement x="147" y="64" width="100" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["D:\\WebService\\Project\\Project-Jasper-Solutions\\images\\internet.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

The template for 5.1.0 version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test-510" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9cac75ed-f737-4990-8094-084771f67298">
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement uuid="36399c1f-8e8e-4148-b777-2ee25b35cc5a" x="147" y="64" width="100" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["D:\\WebService\\Project\\Project-Jasper-Solutions\\images\\internet.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your sample (second template) works for me. I've tried the *iReport 5.1.0*

Comment: Did you start both applications as administrator? You are using Windows version? Maybe it is a permissions issue

Comment: Yes Alex and Thanks in advance for your time, I am using windows version and not using as Administrator just Normal user. Folder permissions are ok. Still not sure, what I am missing.

Comment: Maybe you should make one try as admin (*Run as Administrator*). Try it

Comment: Actually tried running through Admin, Uninstalled, installed and ran. Oops, no luck. Still same boat sailing no where to go.

Comment: It was downloaded from [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-5.1.0/iReport-5.1.0.zip/download)

Comment: Usually I'm using *exe* installer. Try this one: [iReport-5.2.0-windows-installer.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-5.2.0/iReport-5.2.0-windows-installer.exe/download). Try to run it as Administrator.

Comment: Are you trying to run this in 4.0.2?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I have two JRXML files (4.0.2/5.1.0). 4.0.2 works where as 5.1.0 gives the hiccup. As Alex suggested, tried admin and even reinstalled and tried 5.2.0 too, no luck. Exact same thing works in 4.0.2. From java all works, just preview in iReport which is throwing the message.

Comment: @Anand It looks like a miracle. Did you try to run first template (created with 4.0.2 version) in *iReport 5.1.0*?

Comment: Gotcha!!!. This problem occurs for [When No Data] = All Sections, No Detail is set. When I set to "No Pages", Error "Error displaying report page. See the console for details" does not popup. Thanks for all the clues and kindly advices. Though error goes off, I cannot preview with property setting.

Comment: @Anand The interesting case. You should post it as an answer to help others.

Comment: @Anand And what about the *iReport 4.0.2*? It does not raise exception with the same *WhenNoData* property?

Comment: @Alex Nope it does not throw up in 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

- Its a very simple problem but looks like big.
- I was also affected by this problem.
- It was so discussing that no error or problem message showing me on
  iReport console.
- ***Finally any how i remove my image palette from my iReport designer
  mode.***
- ***Then it show me the normal result !!!!!!!***
- I was so surprised.
- Then i understand that something wrong on that image and then i
  change my effected image from report image directory and set another
  one and again select an image palette on report.
- Now it works good.
- I thing it can solve your problem.

[image: Remove This image palette]

Comment: Interesting, Let me give a try

Comment: What about your problem? is that solved bro? If done then vote for me,,,please?